# how to list tailscale devices from the cli?

Tags: command-line-interface, tailscale

I am a recent tailscale user. I am trying to ssh between devices in my tailnet - but I do not want to continuously check device names in my tailscale dashboard. Is there any way to list tailnet devices with the cli?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [`tailscale status`](https://tailscale.com/kb/1080/cli/#status) address your need?

If not, you can generate an API key from [Keys](https://login.tailscale.com/admin/settings/keys) and then use the API:

And grab your `Organization` from [`General`](https://login.tailscale.com/admin/settings/general)

```bash
BASE_URL="https://api.tailscale.com/api/v2"

TAILNET="" # Replace with Organization
TOKEN=""   # Replace with API Key

curl \
--silent \
--location \
--get \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
${BASE_URL}/tailnet/${TAILNET}/devices \
| jq -r .devices[].name
```

Comment: Oh yes, how could I have missed the `status` command? Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome!